# Is a sample statistic a random sequence?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, random-variables, sequence-of-function

In my statistics textbook I find the following line:

We now consider a general sequence of random variables that we denote by $\{Y_{n}\}_{n \ge 1}$ or simply $Y_{n}$. Note that in many applications $Y_{n}$ will be a statistic and thus a function of another sequence $X_{1} , X_{2} , .. ,X_{n}$ of underlying random variables. Why is a statistic that is a function of another sequence a sequence in itself? I can't find anything on the properties of functions of random sequences.

Comment: Take the sample average, for example, $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/n$...

Comment: But why is $Y_{n}$ in this case a sequence? I thought a sequence has more than one entries inside of it, while the sample mean is only one value.

Comment: You have $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\dots$, which is a sequence.